# How to run JNLP deployed java application with SQLite database?

Tags: java, sqlite, jnlp

Hello I have deployed my application made in netbeans. I am using java web start so i got this JNLP file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="http://fuuu.sk/" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
<information>
    <title>PocketBrain</title>
    <vendor>zatokar</vendor>
    <homepage href="www.fuuu.sk"/>
    <description>PocketBrain</description>
    <description kind="short">PocketBrain</description>
</information>
<update check="always"/>
<security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.7+"/>
    <jar href="PocketBrain.jar" main="true"/>
<jar href="lib/sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/eclipselink.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jcalendar-1.4.jar"/>
<extension href="jnlpcomponent1.jnlp"/>
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="model.BrainInPocket">
</application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Everything looks great application is downloaded and installed just it has one problem, it shows an error connecting to database: Error: [SQLITE_ERROR]SQL error or missing database (no such table:...)
I have sqlite file but I dont know where to put it and how to connect it(so it would be in sand box as well). Should I write it into jnlp file as I did it with jars or? The database is stored in: tasks.sqlite. The file is already on a server. It is connected through application:

```
public class SQLiteConnection {

public static PreparedStatement ps = null;
public static Connection con=null;

public static void connect() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:tasks.sqlite");
}
}
```

In netbeans it is working on the server not. Please give me any answer. It looks like it is not able to find tasks.sqlite even though it is right there on the same place. But if I understand it correctly files which are needed to run the app are downloaded in user's temp files (sandbox maybe) and they run from there. But again if i understand correctly files are downloaded only those which are written in JNLP file but tasks.sqlite is not ... so maybe. Anyway, please show what I said wrong or any help???

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).  It shows at least one element out of order ATM (in pink/red).  BTW - where is the DB at the moment?  On a server?  In a Jar file?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I am always checking it with JaNeLA and everything looks all right. DB is called tasks.sqlite it is sqlite file and i just uploaded it in public_html file as other JNLP and jar files. I just have no idea how to connect it. In the appliation i have made connection to that sqlite DB and in NetBeans it is working but how to put sqlite file to that sandbox or whatever as well? Thank you so much!